# R: calculate manually rpart relative error for class method (iris dataset)

Tags: r, rpart

I fitted the following tree

```
library(rpart)    
treeResult = rpart(Species~., data=iris[1:120,], method="class")
```

and am trying to calculate the yellow number below (0.285714) manually.

[image]

I thought this should be the relative reduction in the Gini impurity if the tree goes from 0 to 1 node:

```
pNode1 = c(50,50,20)/120
pNode2 = c(50,0,0)/50
pNode3 = c(0,50,20)/70
# The counts used to calculate these pNodes are taken from summary(treeResult).

impurityNode1 = sum(pNode1*(1-pNode1))
impurityNode2 = sum(pNode2*(1-pNode2))
impurityNode3 = sum(pNode3*(1-pNode3))

relativeError = (50/120*impurityNode2+70/120*impurityNode3) / impurityNode1
```

However, this yields 0.3809524 instead of 0.285714.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. It is not relative Gini impurity. This is displaying relative total impurity.

At the top level node, the impurity is 70/120 = 0.58333.  After the first split, one node perfectly classifies 50 points and the other node has a 50/20 split. So there are 20 errors out of 120 points and the impurity at that level is 20/120 = 0.16666. The relative impurity being computed is

```
(20/120) / (70/120) = 0.16666/0.58333 = 0.285714
```

For completeness, after the second split there are 3 errors. Relative to the original 70 errors we have 3/70 = 0.042857  (the number that it says next to nsplit=2).

Comment: Thanks for explaining! But that does make me curious: what is the difference between setting parms = list(split="information") (entropy impurity) and parms = list(split="gini") (gini impurity)?

Comment: That is the basis on which it _makes_ the split.maximizing the  change in either Gini or entropy. Neither one is exactly what is reported by `printcp` although that might have been useful.

Comment: I see! Do you know if somewhere in the rpart output object (“treeResult”) I can find information about the impurity index (gini or entropy)? Like the overall impurity, impurity per node or improvements in impurity caused by adding nodes? (I looked but can’t find it.)

Comment: I do not see that stored in the output object.